# Is there a way to get the first emails sent by two users to my gmail by using Gmail API? My code gets for one users first email to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

This code gets me a particular users first message to me in gmail using gmail api.

How to get two particular users first message in my gmail using gmail-api
 Can i use if else statements here?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import time

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX
#results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',maxResults=10,labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='googlecommunityteam-noreply@google.com',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()

messages = results.get('messages', [])



if not messages:
    print ("\nGmail: \n No gmail mails found.\n")
else:
    print ("Gmail:\n")

    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[0]['id']).execute()
    print(msg['snippet'])
    print(msg['internalDate'])




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q paramater in Gmail searching works exactly like searching in the Gmail website so if you go to gmail and click on the arrow to the right in the search box.  Up will pop the search builder

[image]

You can play around in this and bring up any type of search you want

```
from:(Test@gmail.com) to:(me@gmail.com)
```

You can then take this and dump it directly into the q in your request

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:(Test@gmail.com) to:(me@gmail.com)',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
```

Now all that being said i played around it and i was unable to get it to return emails by two different users if you put in two email addresses it only returns emails where they both where in the field.  So the only way i think you are going to be able to find the first email sent to you by two diffrent users would be to do

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:(user1@gmail.com) to:(me@gmail.com)',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:(user2@gmail.com) to:(me@gmail.com)',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
```

Comment: for searching a keyword in email can we use this q='from:(user1@gmail.com) to:(me@gmail.com)'  has:football     so football keyword present in these two can be found ?